# Telegram authorization without default button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, telegram, telegram-bot

The only documented way to use Telegram 3-rd party authorization is to use their script that is being provided at https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login

This script (as I digged) works in pretty strange way

1. It renders "Log in with Telegram" button inside the `iframe` with another extra `script` that loads some Telegram entities to work with (like `TWidgetLogin`, `TSticker` **(?)**, `TVideo` **(??)**, `TAudio` **(???)** and some others).
2. By clicking on button, this `iframe` opens new window that is performing authorization.
3. After authorization is being completed, this window is being closed, and since it's done, the `iframe` checks the authorization again. If it's done in right way, the `iframe` retrieves all shared user info and dependent on type of authorization end calls `data-onauth` or sends request to `data-auth-url`.

This behaviour is really unusable for me, because we are also using Google , Github and Facebook OAuths nearby, and all of them are providing the normal usable API to open authorization windows manually and do redirects to specified url.

I mean, that's how our, for example, Google authorization works:

1. User clicks on button that is created **on our own**, customized to match our application style.
2. On click, our application creates new window with url `https://hostname/some/path/to/auth?and_some_params=here`
3. Our server catches this and redirects to Google OAuth consent screen.
4. After Google authorization is being completed, it redirects user to another `/some/path/to/completed_authorization`
5. Server retrieves all necessary information, and redirects window to `/some/path/to/success_authorization` that has script with `window.postMessage` to parent window with authorization info.
6. Parent window (application window) catches this message, closes window and fills storage with given user data.

And thats done. Since opened window is being opened by application, it can be controlled and closed when it's not in use (e.g. when another auth window is being opened, or when the application tab is being closed).

What is unsuitable in telegram "Log in with telegram" button is:

1. No possibility to stylize button to match application style
2. No possibility to change content of the button (in our case it is necessary, because our application is multilanguage).
3. No possibility to control opened window (it is being opened even if the main window is closed)

---

For now I can open a window with Telegram OAuth screen using

```
// some code above
this.popup = window.open("https://oauth.telegram.org/auth?bot_id=<my_bot_id>&origin=http%3A%2F%2F<mydevorigin>&request_access=write, "authWindow", <some window params>)
// some code below
```

But since authorization is being completed, I cannot set anything to let server know that it should retrieve user data and redirect to my page with `window.postMessage`

Is there any way to achieve Telegram authorization without their "Login with Telegram" button? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Telegram has introduced https://telegram.org/blog/privacy-discussions-web-bots#meet-seamless-web-bots recently. Maybe you can use it as an alternative.

Comment: Would it be possible to visually hide the iframe and trigger a click on it when the user clicks on your styled button? I know this is a bit hacky and won't fix the issue of it opening a new tab/ window but it might be better than nothing.

Comment: @DysphoricUnicorn nope, because the `iframe` loads content from `https://core.telegram.org/auth/embed` and I have no access via JS to this button :(

Comment: @AliHashemi Thank you a lot, I will check it deeper. But as far as I understood, this is a kind of server-less authorization. Or it requires implemetation of some bot logic, which is not suitable for our backend developer for obvious reasons :(

Comment: I had the same issue (with wanting to have the same style as google oauth) and I've used the hacky way @DysphoricUnicorn suggested. it works pretty good.

about the issue you mentioned of not having access to the JS button, the iframe provides the data as a "push" event to the parent element of the iframe. (being your JS). If you're interested, I can provide my workaround as an answer.

Comment: @Limbo Hello! I'm a backend developer with the same problem. I've get iframe code, but coudn't move afterwards. Could you please provide found solution step-by-step for backend devs:) Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 19):

So there is an even easier way to do it, without directly listening to `postMessages`.

Telegram widget script https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js adds `Telegram` object to the `window`, this object has `Login` property, which has `auth` function.

`auth` function accepts `options` and `callback`, like so:

```
declare const auth: (options: Options, callback: Callback) => void;

interface Options {
  bot_id: string;
  request_access?: boolean;
  lang?: string;
}

interface Data {
  auth_date: number;
  first_name: string;
  hash: string;
  id: number;
  last_name: string;
  username: string;
  // I think there could be other properties too
}

type Callback = (dataOrFalse: Data | false) => void;
```

Pay attention that `callback` will be called with `false` boolean if authorization is not successful.

So all you need to do is load widget script (without data attributes, because otherwise it will initialise iframe with button), then call this function whenever you need:

```
window.Telegram.Login.auth(
  { bot_id: 'YOUR_BOT_ID', request_access: true },
  (data) => {
    if (!data) {
      // authorization failed
    }

    // Here you would want to validate data like described there https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#checking-authorization
    doWhateverYouWantWithData(data);
  }
);
```

`auth` will open another window with Telegram authorization interface and will listen to this window post messages by itself. When window closes your `callback` will be called.

Comment: So this above works perfectly. Now how do I access the userpic? I can see the API response from https://oauth.telegram.org/auth/get has html, origin and user. The user key appears in the data in the above code. The html key has the image link sitting inside, but I dont see how I can access it.

Comment: This does not work — bot_id should be either domain or actual numeric id and neither of them works. When I pass username the script requires "bot id" (as it parses int inside js), and when I pass numeric ID I get "Bot domain invalid" error

Comment: @VityaSchel `bot_id` is a string type consisting of numbers, it looks like this `"123456789"`. Don't try to pass domain name or bot nickname there, just use bot id. Do not to use `bot_token` here either, although it will work, you should not expose it on the client side. If you are getting domain error then you have misconfigured domain name, double check it.

Answer (score 7):

@Limbo as I can see - the generated widget and code just create an iframe with the content based on our bot name and other params. It each time the same.
For example for (https://oauth.telegram.org/embed/samplebot?origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.telegram.org&size=medium&userpic=false), the interested part in response is here:

```
<div class="tgme_widget_login medium nouserpic" id="widget_login"><button class="btn tgme_widget_login_button" onclick="return TWidgetLogin.auth();"><i class="tgme_widget_login_button_icon"></i>Log in with Telegram</button></div>

<script src="//telegram.org/js/widget-frame.js?27"></script>
<script>TWidgetLogin.init('widget_login', 547043436, {"origin":"https:\/\/core.telegram.org"}, false, "en");
```

And it will be the same each time. So, you just add this code to your page whre you can customize the button styles, and put in any place of the page as you want. Just take care of id param and not forget to add an event listener for onClick which will call the TWidgetLogin.auth() when you want to show the login popup.

The TWidgetLogin.init function accepts couple of the params (target_login_btn_id, bot_id, params, init_auth, lang). All of them is self-described.

The interesting part - is about the getting auth info. If you check that widget-frame.js you will find that after successful auth it calls `window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), origin || '*');` with user data in data param. In our case (we operate without iframe) the postMessage will be delivered to the current window and you will be able to catch it with simple code

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {console.log('get message, evetn)}, false);
```

And its where you can get all user data that you need.

The only thing - the origin of that message. But this param scripts gets with user data from telegram servers, so I suspect that it will contain the linked site origin and we will not have any problems with that.

Good luck with further investigation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a kind of things that I've tried, but not in this way. As far as I undestand, this will cause Telegram OAuth window to post message to my application, but our backend won't catch the authorization fact in this case, so frontend should do this manually. There are some pros, but the main cons is that we can control the style and content of the button and this solves problem partially :)

Comment: Yes, you will be forced to send that auth data to backend by your code, but that code is very simple and as you can see Telegram not provide oAuth in the "classic" way.

Comment: @MykolaPrymak 
Hello! I'm a backend developer with the same problem. I've get iframe code, but coudn't move afterwards. Could you please provide solution step-by-step for backend devs:) Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: I have same code but I'm opening a tab with this url - file:///auth?bot_id=547043436&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.telegram.org&embed=1&request_access=write

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning if you have `"Prevent Cross-Site Tracking" enabled` in **Safari** or `"Allow Cross-Website Tracking" disabled` in **Chrome** you won't be able to authorize since widget will not send any data