# Custom trigger button for authentication with Telegram

Tags: javascript, oauth, telegram, telegram-bot

### This is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347902/telegram-authorization-without-default-button), whose answer doesn't seem to work as on June 10, 2020

Hello, everyone.

I'm facing the exact same issue @Limbo described in that question. I'd like to ping the author, but simply don't have enough reputation to leave a comment... ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Long story short:
I'm working on implementation of Telegram's authentication via [it's widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login). Naturally, I'd like to customize default "Log in"-button. The problem is the fact that Telegram provides such possibility only via `<iframe>`, which means that "Log in"-button can't be reached neither via JS, nor via CSS.

Is there any other way to make stylized trigger of authentication window (e.g. by bypassing of cross-domain restriction, or by creation of own button on native origin)?

The only solution I see now - is to `transform: scale(); visibility: hidden;` iframe's container and make it overlap an element, which were supposed to trigger authentication window, via `position: absolute; z-index: 2;`. But that seems to be a kludge. Very bad one.

---

### Why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56446184/11797968) doesn't work:

The author proposes to catch authentication payload via `"message"`-listener. Due to mine investigation, it is not possible, as at 3-d step of flow (see picture) Telegram runs `postMessage`-function for `window.opener`, which is `<iframe>`-element, and specifies that event should be available only for `https://oauth.telegram.org`. Thus, it is not possible to catch it on any other origin.

[image]

Comment: I've added another answer how to do it, please check it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593384/5650447